# Why my Computer re-starts at time of power outage?

Tags: reboot, ups

My computer (sometimes) shuts down for a fraction of second and then restarts at time of power outage. The most weird thing happening is that when I switch off the electric supply of UPS (ie. where UPS is connected to socket), it back up the computer normally, I mean without any re-boot happening. But when there is power outage the computer re-start.

I have the best available UPS (I have just replaced the battery), connected to my IBM Think Centre desktop. Recently I got computer SMPS (power supply) replaced. Can that be the reason of this problem ? because this issue has surfaced only after I got the power supply replaced. My previous SMPS was 230 Watts (which got fried due to power surge) the new one is of a company called CIL Odyessy (ATX) 450 watts.

Do you think the new SMPS is not doing what it should have done at time of power outage. I read somewhere that SMPS have capacitors which provide power back up to CPU for milliseconds (like 1-2 ms) till the UPS takes over. Can that be the cause ?

Please note at time of power outage, out of 10  re-starting happens 7 times.

What is the reason behind this strange problem and how can I solve it ?

I have tried changing the UPS, connected UPS to other points in house, plugged CPU to different points behind UPS, isolated other equipments from UPS (like directly plugged TFT monitor, speaker to main lines so that CPU gets dedicated power) and done many other things, but no success !!

Thanking you all in advance.

Comment: What is the model of your UPS.  Is your UPS line-interactive?

Comment: tried UPS with some other system?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why PC reboots when there’s a power failure even with UPS?](http://superuser.com/questions/127636/why-pc-reboots-when-there-s-a-power-failure-even-with-ups)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess that your power "outages" are not causing power to be suddenly cut to the UPS but instead involve an initial "sag" of the power that is severe enough to trigger the computer's power supply sensing of power lost, but is not severe enough to cause the UPS to kick in.  This could indeed be due in part to changing computer power supplies, with the new one having a slightly different threshold.

It may be that there is a setting for the UPS to tell it to kick in sooner.  Otherwise, you should probably replace the UPS with one that will more reliably trigger.

Comment: Do you think the SMPS is not doing what it should have done at time of power outage. I read somewhere that SMPS have capacitors which provide power back up to CPU for milliseconds (like 1-2 ms) till the UPS takes over. Can that be the cause for further evaluation ?

Comment: You could get a wattmeter to hook in between the UPS and your computer, which might show the power dip.

Comment: Yes, it could be that the replacement PS does not have the same capacity to handle dips of a given time duration that the old one did (though normally one with a higher wattage would be expected to do better).  (Note that all power supplies must be capable of handling a "dip" of about 1/120 second, in order to sufficiently filter the 60Hz power line.)

Comment: Also note that the original power surge may have damaged the UPS.

Comment: Thanks a lot DanH for taking out time for answering to my question.  Your feedback really helped me to move in right direction. I will surely change the power supply and try to find a quality equivalent or better than the original one. :)

Comment: I have posted on more question on superuser but I would appreciate your feedback. The question posted is as follows: I am going to buy a new PSU of CORSAIR for my IBM thinkcentre desktop. My previous original PSU was of 230 watts. I have not added any hardware in the CPU. It's in same condition as it was when I bought. On that basis, please suggest which power supply of Corsair and of how many watts will be suitable for me to buy, after referring to the under given weblink.

http://www.corsair.com/en/power-supply-units.html

Comment: @arayman -- Sorry, I don't do much in the way of PC maintenance anymore.  And that IBM is probably pretty old iron, with limited options anyway.  Just pick something of decent quality, with 230-350 watt capacity.

Comment: Thanks DanH for your valued advice. I got your point, will go for a good power supply. :)

Answer (score 0):

If the new PSU is not rated at something like 65-250 V then it is sensitive to undervoltage. You should either change the PSU (which you might not want to as you say it is rather new) or reconfigure the UPS to kick in at a lower (RMS) voltage.