# My computer that is plugged into an UPS reboots when the power goes down

Tags: windows-7, reboot, ups

I am using a Seasonic SS 400et active PFC F3 power supply, but my computer reboots when the power goes down. The computer's processor is an Intel Core 2 Quad Q6600. I have 6 GB RAM and a GTS 250 512 MB graphics card. What can I do to find and fix my issue?

Comment: Is the battery in the UPS healthy?  What other devices are connected to the UPS?  What is the total wattage of all devices connected to the UPS?

Comment: There is another test.  Disconnect the UPS from the wall then try to start all devices connected to it.  If the UPS cannot even power the devices on then the problem is the UPS itself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why PC reboots when there’s a power failure even with UPS?](http://superuser.com/questions/127636/why-pc-reboots-when-there-s-a-power-failure-even-with-ups), [Why my Computer re-starts at time of power outage?](http://superuser.com/questions/438981/why-my-computer-re-starts-at-time-of-power-outage) ...

Comment: What model is your UPS? You probably need a pure sine wave UPS for your system to function correctly on battery.

Comment: Something is wrong if your computer reboots when the power goes down. It should either power down too (faulty ups or something else) or stay up until the upc is exhausted.

Comment: ups is NS 1000va/660w.Battery is in new condition.

Answer (score 3):

#### A power supply with active PFC requires a pure sine wave UPS to function correctly on battery power.

- AC mains power is provided as a sine wave, smoothly alternating back and forth at a rate of 50 or 60 cycles per second. However, most less expensive UPS units provide a simulated sine wave, which uses a square wave to roughly approximate mains power. While less sensitive electronics may function correctly on a simulated sine wave, some devices, such as a PC with an active PFC PSU, may not work.
- Midrange models often use a stepped sine wave, which is similar but has intermediate steps between the high and low voltage points. Although this is better than a simulated sine wave and a broader range devices will function correctly on stepped sine wave input, it is still less than ideal. Better models will produce output waveforms with more steps between the peaks and troughs for smoother power.
- The best UPS units provide a pure sine wave that is more or less identical to mains power. Your active PFC power supply expects pure sine wave input, so you'll need to invest in a more expensive UPS to get this functionality. These UPS units also tend to provide better protection against power transients and mains voltage variations, which can reduce the risk of equipment failure due to power disruptions.

[image: Different types of output from UPS units]
<sup>*[Image source](http://www.edaboard.com/thread232279.html)*</sup>

Answer (score 0):

If that's a 400W UPS, as I suspect it is, you might simply be over-budget.

If you exceed a UPS' wattage (or the battery is worn out) it will instantly shut off to prevent the battery from overheating and eventually exploding.

How big is the PSU in your PC? What about your monitor's (or monitors') power draw? Those should be listed on the adapters, along with any printers or other accessories.

Also, if the UPS has a USB jack you can connect it to your PC and use HWMonitor to check its battery health rating.